# Remove Padding between drawableTop and text

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have CustomLayout which has TextView on which I am setting text and drawable programmatically however the problem is when I set the drawable it is adding a huge padding with what I want is drawable to be more at the center rather than at the top.

**Custom ViewGroup**

```
public class ProfileGridView extends FrameLayout {
public ProfileGridView(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);
    initView(context,null);
}

public ProfileGridView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initView(context,attrs);

}

public ProfileGridView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initView(context,attrs);
}

@TargetApi(21)
public ProfileGridView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    initView(context,attrs);
}

public void initView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TextView gridTextView;
    View view = inflate(context, R.layout.square_grid, null);
    gridTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_description);

    TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ProfileGridView);
    Drawable drawable = array.getDrawable(R.styleable.ProfileGridView_drawble);
    String description = array.getString(R.styleable.ProfileGridView_grid_description);

    gridTextView.setText(description);
    gridTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, drawable, null, null);
    addView(view);
    array.recycle();
   }
}
```

**CustomView LayoutFile**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/grid_description"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:drawablePadding="8dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="0dp"
android:textSize="20sp" />
```

**MainActivit.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <com.example.views.ProfileGridView
      android:layout_width="200dp"
      android:layout_height="200dp"
      app:drawble="@drawable/ic_message"
      app:grid_description="Message"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot of the View]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use a CustomView LayoutFile like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="52dp"
    android:layout_height="52dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And set the drawable like this

```
    ImageView image;
    image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Instead of

```
gridTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, drawable, null, null);
```

**EDIT**

As you ask, you can make ProfileGridView wrap_content instead of 200dp. With setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds you attach the drawable to the bounds of the TextView (200dp). [You can check the documentation for more info](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))

Comment: I guess this is the only way to do it but instead of using LinearLayout I thought of using TextView to set ImageDrawable top

Comment: by attack the drawable bound you mean set TextView height to 200dp and add wrap_content to it's height in activity_main

Comment: @prathamkesarkar Sorry, attach. And set height and width to wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a padding problem, is because you are setting the drawable width and height as 200dp

Can you use "wrap_content" in the drawable file?

If not just have a image file and set it as a drawable of the TextView

Comment: Just try setting the width and height as 40dp or something and you will see is not the padding

Comment: I tried setting height in textview to 64dp but it is still showing me the same thing it seems like drawable is trying to use all the available  space

Comment: Try change the Drawable RelativeLayout width too pls, from match_parent to wrap_content or even the 64dp you said

Comment: why width  the space is between text and drawable

Comment: seems like there is some bug in Textview when trying to set property programatically

Comment: Try doing in the xml of the TextView `android:drawableTop="@styleable/ProfileGridView_drawble"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139873/discussion-between-pratham-kesarkar-and-diogo-rosa).

Answer (score 0):

Setting the drawableBottom to an equally sized image will recenter the text. Here is a simple drawable that would do the trick:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"/>
</shape>
```